# Different Result on Stratified k-fold Cross Validation

Tags: r, cross-validation

Now I am doing SVM to classify observation from Microarray Dataset and the result is accuracy. I use stratified 10-fold cross validation and run those program on R (I use my own script because caret Package cannot work on my R)

Here I have some questions, 1. Why the result of accuracy is mostly different in each run?, 2. Should I divide the data into 10 fold first, and use that data in each time I run the program?

I think the accuracy is different in each run because every time, when I run the program, they will divide the data into 10 fold, and the fold's member also different. Is it true?

Comment: How much different?. What do you use CV for?. Feature or parameter selection?

Answer (score 1):

You need to give more information like what is the datset size, class distribution etc, but here is a quick answer.

It's natural for the accuracy to be different across folds, the question is how much.

If the standard deviation of the accuracies across folds is high, that could mean that your folds are not split comparably with respect to the class distributions and you might consider a stratified split scheme.

Comment: I use Colon Cancer Dataset by Alon et. al. It contains 62 observation, 40 of them are Tumor and 22 are Normal. The accuracy of each fold is not much different, but the value is not exactly the same.

Comment: why do you expect them to be exactly the same?

Comment: I dont expect them to be exactly the same. I just wondering why the value is different. And then I think that it because, everytime if I run the program, they will divide the data into 10 fold, and the fold's member also different.